# How to parse evtx log output of wusa command?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, update

Worked out how to script install of **.msu** updates.

```
$filename = "C:\temp\log\WUInstall_" + $timer + ".evtx"
Start-Process -FilePath wusa -ArgumentList "\\fs1\software\WS2012R2\windows8.1-kb4041693-x64_31e473824b705bf05f3befc423d39fa0c6d0fb49.msu /quiet /norestart /log:$filename" -Wait
```

Using **wusa** with Powershell as this is the only way to avoid a machine restart after the update - as I need to wait for this one to complete and run a couple more commands, before issuing a manual restart (`/norestart` requires `/quiet` as well). 
Not able to log the outcome of the installation to a clear-text format, it's **.evtx** only.

Let's just say that the update is already installed (could be an already patched OS image, no control over this) and I run the script. It just runs, no error. 
When executed without `/quiet /norestart` it will eventually print "<..> is already installed on this computer."
Also, in **.evtx** log there are a few lines that show the status of the install process, including "InstallWorker.01090: Update is already installed". But I have no knowledge on how to parse this log. I can only parse a plain text log.

Is there a way to parse the **.evtx** log ? so that I can put some logic in my script to check the status (update installed ok or not) and decide on an action ? (move to next step in the script or quit with error)

Or a better solution to solve this in Powershell 5.1 ? Should be able to apply it to WS 2012 through 2016.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-WinEvent -Path $PathToFile
```

That should work assuming it's really a .evtx file.

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't work with my log file, but is able to open an export file from Event Viewer. Guess the format is different. I can open the wusa log with Event Viewer though... Also found the tracerpt command, but couldn't figure out the correct config to parse the log generated by wusa.

Answer (score 1):

First, I am pretty sure that the log file generated by that would not be anything other than an ASCII format log file. Naming it `.evtx` only makes it confusing.

Rather than parsing a log file to look for known lines, the function that is built for whether the command succeeded or failed is the `return code` or `exit code`. This should get you started:

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = $commandPath
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = $commandArguments
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
[pscustomobject]@{
    commandTitle = $commandTitle
    stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    ExitCode = $p.ExitCode  
}
$p.WaitForExit()
```

After you get the return code, this may be helpfull:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/938205/windows-update-error-code-list